# Cannot export Google My Maps as KML with network link

Tags: google-maps, kml

I made a map in Google My Maps and want to export it as a KML file with the network link feature enabled. With network link enabled any changes made in the My Maps editor will reflect in the KML file when it updates over the network link.

When clicking on "Expot to KML" in My Maps the following dialogue box has an option "Keep data up to date with network link KML (only usable online)" with a check box next to it. The ability to check the box has been disabled. How can I export a KML with the network link enabled? Am I missing a specific requirement?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map must be public for the network link option to work (it will be grayed out if the map isn't public).

Additional information can be found regarding this matter:

[**Link**](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3109452?hl=en)

Comment: Your answer is correct, thanks, but I cannot make the map public so it seems mymaps will not work for me.